# NSIS ExecWait fails with error code -1073741515

Tags: nsis

Hi i have problems with execwait. Here is some code:

```
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\myDir"
ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\myDir\Myexe.exe"' $0
```

This fails and the error code in $0 is -1073741515
The path and the exe exist.
If i run the same setup a second time this code works fine, the exe is executed and no error code is set.
What am i doing wrong? Any idea?

Comment: There is no dll missing. i can run the exe from install dir.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a problem with Myexe.exe and not NSIS. To be sure you have to figure out if the [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call inside `ExecWait` failed or if this is just the exit code from the program:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh

Section
ClearErrors
ExecWait '"$SysDir\Charmap.exe"' $0
${If} ${Errors}
    MessageBox mb_iconstop "Unable to start program!"
${Else}
    MessageBox mb_ok "Program started successfully, the program exited with code $0"
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

If you get the "Program started successfully" message but the program still fails then perhaps there is something that needs to be registered for the program to work successfully and the registration is complete the next time you run it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

What i get is "Program started successfully, the program exited with code -1073741515"
But what i don't understand is, while the messagebox is still open i can execute the exe from install dir, which let's me think that there is no registration missing.

Comment: You could try to monitor it with Process Monitor to see if you can spot any differences when running it for the 2nd time.

Comment: i couldn't spot anything in the process monitor....
But i've added a messagebox before the execWait command. At that time i can execute the exe from cmd without any problems.
But when i continue the setup, execWait will give me the error message. How can that be?

I'm lost. I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: In my setup i install some redistributables, that are needed for the exe. I think the environment is not set correctly for the setup, so the exe can not be executed from the setup correctly. Is there a way i can execute the exe from the setup, with the correct environment?

Comment: is there a way to refresh the environment during the setup?